# Bash hangs when trying to create file or issue ls on raid mount point

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, lsi

I have /dev/sdb1 mounted to /media/zm_recordings. I'm using an LSI 9211-4i RAID controller with two 500GB disks in RAID 1. Megaraid manager shows the disks and volumes as healthy. (Screenshot at bottom)

fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 464.7 GiB, 498999492608 bytes, 974608384 sectors
Disk model: Logical Volume
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CA56483A-DA09-4FCC-A0D7-B35BE76180D7
```

If I run `strace ls /media/zm_recordings` I get

```
    execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls", "zm_recordings/"], 0x7fff11df0818 /* 24 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558dfbd85000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=81219, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 81219, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3dec49f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@k\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=155296, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3dec49d000
mmap(NULL, 2259632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3dec275000
mprotect(0x7f3dec29a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3dec499000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7f3dec499000
mmap(0x7f3dec49b000, 6832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3dec49b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1824496, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1837056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3dec0b4000
mprotect(0x7f3dec0d6000, 1658880, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3dec0d6000, 1343488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f3dec0d6000
mmap(0x7f3dec21e000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16a000) = 0x7f3dec21e000
mmap(0x7f3dec26b000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7f3dec26b000
mmap(0x7f3dec271000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3dec271000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=468944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 471304, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3dec040000
mmap(0x7f3dec042000, 335872, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3dec042000
mmap(0x7f3dec094000, 122880, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x54000) = 0x7f3dec094000
mmap(0x7f3dec0b2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x71000) = 0x7f3dec0b2000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\21\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 16656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3dec03b000
mmap(0x7f3dec03c000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f3dec03c000
mmap(0x7f3dec03d000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3dec03d000
mmap(0x7f3dec03e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3dec03e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=146968, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 132288, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3dec01a000
mmap(0x7f3dec020000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f3dec020000
mmap(0x7f3dec02f000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f3dec02f000
mmap(0x7f3dec035000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a000) = 0x7f3dec035000
mmap(0x7f3dec037000, 13504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3dec037000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3dec018000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3dec019380) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3dec26b000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3dec035000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3dec03e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3dec0b2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3dec499000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x558dfbc3f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3dec4da000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3dec49f000, 81219)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f3dec019650)         = 1391
set_robust_list(0x7f3dec019660, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f3dec0206b0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f3dec02c730}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f3dec020740, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f3dec02c730}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffe3d5dd9d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffe3d5dd9d0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558dfbd85000
brk(0x558dfbda6000)                     = 0x558dfbda6000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 324
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3031696, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3031696, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3debd33000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=28, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
stat("zm_recordings/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "zm_recordings/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3
```

At this point nothing else appears in the console, I can issue ctrl + c but nothing happens.

I also can't create a file in this directory, however it was working OK yesterday.

fstab:

```
/dev/sdb1  /media/zm_recordings    ext4    defaults    0    1
```

sudo dmesg | grep -i lsi:

```
[    2.586136] mpt2sas_cm0: LSISAS2008: FWVersion(07.00.00.00), ChipRevision(0x0                2), BiosVersion(07.11.00.00)
[   10.561060] scsi 0:1:0:0: Direct-Access     LSI      Logical Volume   3000 PQ                : 0 ANSI: 6
[   17.662068] Copyright (c) 1999-2008 LSI Corporation
```

sudo dmesg | grep -i sdb:

```
[   10.589573] sd 0:1:0:0: [sdb] 974608384 512-byte logical blocks: (499 GB/465 GiB)
[   10.589600] sd 0:1:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   10.589601] sd 0:1:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 08
[   10.589624] sd 0:1:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   10.589659] sd 0:1:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   10.620603]  sdb: sdb1
[   10.621079] sd 0:1:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   16.826487] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I tried to unmount the drive and remount:

strace mount /dev/sdb1 /media/test

```
execve("/usr/bin/mount", ["mount", "/dev/sdb1", "/media/test"], 0x7fff063b7890 /* 14 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5651bd077000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=83174, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 83174, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3073470000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\332\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=383456, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f307346e000
mmap(NULL, 386344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f307340f000
mprotect(0x7f307341b000, 323584, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f307341b000, 245760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc000) = 0x7f307341b000
mmap(0x7f3073457000, 73728, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x48000) = 0x7f3073457000
mmap(0x7f307346a000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5a000) = 0x7f307346a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@k\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=155296, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2259632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f30731e7000
mprotect(0x7f307320c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f307340b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7f307340b000
mmap(0x7f307340d000, 6832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f307340d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1824496, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1837056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3073026000
mprotect(0x7f3073048000, 1658880, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3073048000, 1343488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f3073048000
mmap(0x7f3073190000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16a000) = 0x7f3073190000
mmap(0x7f30731dd000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7f30731dd000
mmap(0x7f30731e3000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f30731e3000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\257\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=343008, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 345896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072fd1000
mprotect(0x7f3072fdb000, 282624, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3072fdb000, 212992, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7f3072fdb000
mmap(0x7f307300f000, 65536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3e000) = 0x7f307300f000
mmap(0x7f3073020000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4e000) = 0x7f3073020000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=35808, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 39904, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072fc7000
mmap(0x7f3072fc9000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3072fc9000
mmap(0x7f3072fcd000, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f3072fcd000
mmap(0x7f3072fcf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7f3072fcf000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=468944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 471304, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072f53000
mmap(0x7f3072f55000, 335872, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3072f55000
mmap(0x7f3072fa7000, 122880, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x54000) = 0x7f3072fa7000
mmap(0x7f3072fc5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x71000) = 0x7f3072fc5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\21\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072f51000
mmap(NULL, 16656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072f4c000
mmap(0x7f3072f4d000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f3072f4d000
mmap(0x7f3072f4e000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3072f4e000
mmap(0x7f3072f4f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3072f4f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 #\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32792, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072f43000
mmap(0x7f3072f45000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3072f45000
mmap(0x7f3072f49000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f3072f49000
mmap(0x7f3072f4a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f3072f4a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=146968, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 132288, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072f22000
mmap(0x7f3072f28000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f3072f28000
mmap(0x7f3072f37000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f3072f37000
mmap(0x7f3072f3d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a000) = 0x7f3072f3d000
mmap(0x7f3072f3f000, 13504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072f3f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072f20000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3072f21100) = 0
mprotect(0x7f30731dd000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3072f3d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3072f4a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3072f4f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3072fc5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3072fcf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3073020000, 20480, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f307340b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f307346a000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x5651bc7aa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f30734ac000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3073470000, 83174)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f3072f213d0)         = 3003
set_robust_list(0x7f3072f213e0, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f3072f286b0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f3072f34730}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f3072f28740, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f3072f34730}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffe5ef37080) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffe5ef37080)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5651bd077000
brk(0x5651bd098000)                     = 0x5651bd098000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 324
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3031696, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3031696, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3072c3b000
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
access("/sys/fs/smackfs", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3540, ...}) = 0
lstat("/dev/sdb1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdb1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
lstat("/media", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/media/test", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/dev/sdb1", F_OK)               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM)   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, [498997395456])  = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:17", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(4, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:17", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
faccessat(4, "partition", F_OK)         = 0
readlink("/sys/dev/block/8:17", "../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00"..., 4095) = 91
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sdb/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(5, "8:16\n", 4096)                 = 5
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
lseek(3, 498997329920, SEEK_SET)        = 498997329920
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 64) = 64
lseek(3, 498997387264, SEEK_SET)        = 498997387264
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(3, "\1\4\0\0\21\4\0\0!\4\0\0\331[\365\37\2\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\f\217\4\256\365\37\200."..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 498997394944, SEEK_SET)        = 498997394944
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 498997263872, SEEK_SET)        = 498997263872
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(3, "\1\4\0\0\21\4\0\0!\4\0\0\331[\365\37\2\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\f\217\4\256\365\37\200."..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 498997391360, SEEK_SET)        = 498997391360
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(3, "\0\300\320\1\0\351B\7\f\362\\\0\333w!\7\365\277\320\1\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 16384, SEEK_SET)               = 16384
read(3, "\0\0\300\0\20\0\300\0 \0\300\0\340_\0 \0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\246d\0\0\0 X\251"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 32768, SEEK_SET)               = 32768
read(3, "\0\0\300\1\20\0\300\1 \0\300\1\340_\0 \0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\246d\0\0\0 K\370"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 65536, SEEK_SET)               = 65536
read(3, "\0\0\300\3\20\0\300\3 \0\300\3\340_\0 \0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\246d\0\0\0 \234,"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 131072, SEEK_SET)              = 131072
read(3, " \200\0\0 \200\1\0 \200\2\0 \200\3\0 \200\4\0 \200\f\0 \200\r\0 \200\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 262144, SEEK_SET)              = 262144
read(3, "@\200\0\0@\200\1\0@\200\2\0@\200\3\0@\200\4\0@\200\f\0@\200\r\0@\200\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 524288, SEEK_SET)              = 524288
read(3, "\200\200\0\0\200\200\1\0\200\200\2\0\200\200\3\0\200\200\4\0\200\200\f\0\200\200\r\0\200\200\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1048576, SEEK_SET)             = 1048576
read(3, "\0\201\0\0\0\201\1\0\0\201\2\0\0\201\3\0\0\201\4\0\0\201\f\0\0\201\r\0\0\201\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 2097152, SEEK_SET)             = 2097152
read(3, "\0\202\0\0\0\202\1\0\0\202\2\0\0\202\3\0\0\202\4\0\0\202\f\0\0\202\r\0\0\202\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 4194304, SEEK_SET)             = 4194304
read(3, "\0\204\0\0\0\204\1\0\0\204\2\0\0\204\3\0\0\204\4\0\0\204\f\0\0\204\r\0\0\204\30\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1048576, SEEK_SET)             = 1048576
read(3, "\0\201\0\0\0\201\1\0\0\201\2\0\0\201\3\0\0\201\4\0\0\201\f\0\0\201\r\0\0\201\30\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 3072, SEEK_SET)                = 3072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 7168, SEEK_SET)                = 7168
read(3, "\0\0000\0\20\0000\0 \0000\0\340_\0 \0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\246d\0\0\0 \311\335"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 15360, SEEK_SET)               = 15360
read(3, "\0\0\260\0\20\0\260\0 \0\260\0\340_\0 \0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\246d\0\0\0 8\316"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 31744, SEEK_SET)               = 31744
read(3, "\0\0\260\1\20\0\260\1 \0\260\1\340_\0 \0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\246d\0\0\0 +\237"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 64512, SEEK_SET)               = 64512
read(3, "\0\0\260\3\20\0\260\3 \0\260\3\334_\364\37\4\0\4\0\0\0\0\0*\350\177\217\364\37Q\311"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072bfa000
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 262144, SEEK_SET)              = 262144
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072bb9000
read(3, "@\200\0\0@\200\1\0@\200\2\0@\200\3\0@\200\4\0@\200\f\0@\200\r\0@\200\30\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 498996871168, SEEK_SET)        = 498996871168
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072b78000
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 498997133312, SEEK_SET)        = 498997133312
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3072b37000
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
lseek(3, 2097152, SEEK_SET)             = 2097152
read(3, "\0\202\0\0\0\202\1\0\0\202\2\0\0\202\3\0\0\202\4\0\0\202\f\0\0\202\r\0\0\202\30\0"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(3, BLKSSZGET, [512])              = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:16", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
readlink("/sys/dev/block/8:16", "../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00"..., 4095) = 86
stat("/dev/sdb", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x10), ...}) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fadvise64(4, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM)   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x10), ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, BLKGETSIZE64, [498999492608])  = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:16", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
openat(5, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:16", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
faccessat(5, "partition", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(5, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(4, CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY, 0)       = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(4, BLKSSZGET, [512])              = 0
lseek(4, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(4, "\257=\306\17\203\204rG\216y=i\330G}\344>Wq/W\r`C\244\332\336\"'\320\314\1"..., 16384) = 16384
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:17", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
openat(5, "size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)   = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(6, "974604288\n", 4096)            = 10
close(6)                                = 0
openat(5, "start", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(6, "2048\n", 4096)                 = 5
close(6)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f3072bfa000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f3072bb9000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f3072b78000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f3072b37000, 266240)          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/sbin/mount.ext4", 0x7ffe5ef34db0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/fs.d/mount.ext4", 0x7ffe5ef34db0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/fs/mount.ext4", 0x7ffe5ef34db0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getegid()                               = 0
prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)                  = 1 (SUID_DUMP_USER)
stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=860, ...}) = 0
lstat("/run/mount/utab", 0x7ffe5ef35ef0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkdir("/run/mount", 0755)               = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/run/mount/utab", 0x7ffe5ef35de0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/run/mount", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/run/mount", R_OK|W_OK)         = 0
mount("/dev/sdb1", "/media/test", "ext4", 0, NULL
```

Again bash just won't output anything here, ctrl + c doesn't do anything other than print ^C.

Not sure where to go from here. Any other checks I can issue? I attached a screenshot of the RAID status screen, I couldn't seem to get the megacli/storcli working but I will continue to try and fix that. (I may be wrong but I believe the storcli command below doesn't work because you have to use megacli for old raid cards like that one I have.)

sudo storcli show all:

```
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
Host Name = debian-zm
Operating System  = Linux4.19.0-6-amd64
```

[Megaraid status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgrzF.png)

Comment: Please check what's in dmesg when running "ls". There may be a filesystem corruption here, that hangs the filesystem.

Comment: I did a reboot which seems to have resolved the problem. The issue seemed to occur overnight so I'm going to assume it will happen again. I'll follow your advice in that case and report back.

I didn't reboot initially because it's luks encrypted and I don't have KVM support.

Comment: A mount of ext4 will often also do a write to the journal of the filesystem. To avoid that completely and see if at least you can read from the filesystem, you can do the following: **mount -o ro,noload -t ext4 /dev/blockdevice /mnt/readonlyfiles**

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a filesystem corruption. At the moment where the commands hang, check the last lines from `dmesg`, there should be hints of a problem there.

Rebooting has the effect of remounting the volume and eventually replay the journal. However if there's some corrupt metadata hiding somewhere, it will freeze again at some point. You should definitely run `e2fsck` on your volume after having unmounted it.